# Why eclipse impose restriction on BASE64Encoder?

Tags: java, eclipse, base64

I came across a scenario where I was required to use `BASE64Encoder` for encoding and decoding.
I found that in eclipse, restriction is on this class.

I want to know is there any specific reason due to which it was done by eclipse developers.
If so,then what is the reason?

**Note:** I am not asking how to resolve `BASE64Encoder` restriction.Rather I want to know the reason for this restriction.

Comment: You might find this helpful
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: @AntiEarth you should post this as an answer - I would have upvoted it! (unless I misunderstand and it doesn't answer the question)

Comment: @AntiEarth : Wayne is right..You should have posted this as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is relevant;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Summarising;
BASE64Encoder is part of a sun.* package, which are *"not part of the public, supported interface"* (as Evgeniy put it, it's used *"for internal purposes"*).

Therefore;
`"A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform."`

I believe I was promised some up-votes c:

Answer (score 2):

BASE64Encoder is used by Oracle JRE for internal purposes, it's not Java public API. Other JREs may not have this class. If you use it in your app it will not be portable.